# Most efficient way to read and edit an xml file

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an xml template file, some fields are blank and need to be filled by my application.
This has to result in an xml string representation of that file which will be given to another routine.

So, let's take this simple xml as example:

```
<root>
   <name anAttr=""></name>
   <age></age>
</root>
```

As you can see I'd have to read the xml and, in the parsing process, add some contents to it.

I though about using a sax parser and in the handler I would do something like this:

```
StringBuilder finalXml = new StringBuilder();

DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler(){

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                            finalXml.append("<"+qName+">");
                            if(qName.equals("name")){
                                finalXml.append("donald");
                             }

        }
```

would it be correct/efficient this way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: SAX is fine, but you can probably make more assumptions about the order of elements rather than check every element - SAX can be stateful. You could also consider unmarshalling the XML with JAXB or some such. Finally, you could use XPath if there are only a few variables.

Comment: This question has been asked an answered many times. Here's an early one, which I found by pasting the text of your title into the search box: [How do I edit a XML node in a file object, using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647512/how-do-i-edit-a-xml-node-in-a-file-object-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) when i have wanted to parse xml in Java, and it's quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice of technology then I would suggest using JAXB .

It will unmarshal the XML into Java Object ,here do the modifications to java Object and then Marshal the modified Java Object into new XML File.

It has little bit of learning curve but code will be readable and maintainable.

for Basic tutorial of JAXB please refer to [URL](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html#jaxb)

Comment: Jaxb asks me to create java pojo bindings..and that is a great waste as, just for editing an xml file, I have to introduce a new package in my application.